# JavaScript - Create date with format string

Tags: javascript, date

In JavaScript would it be possible to create a date using a format string?

Example:

```js
new Date('10/12/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy');

new Date('12/10/2020', 'mm/dd/yyyy');

new Date('2020/01/20', 'yyyy/mm/dd');

new Date('2020-01-20', 'yyyy-mm-dd');

new Date('2020 01 20', 'yyyy mm dd');
```

All of those would create a new valid date.

Comment: `momentjs` or `Date.parse()`

Comment: JavaScript's standard library doesn't have anything that does that, no. There are **lots** of date handling libraries out there (such as Moment) that do, though. @Justinas - No, `Date.parse` doesn't support a format string (or create a `Date`, come to that :-) ).

Comment: Don't use momentJS though. The project has been deprecated in favour of [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript does not support creating date with string format. You can use any of the following libraries for formatting,

1. moment.js (https://momentjs.com/)
2. Luxon(https://moment.github.io/luxon/)
3. date-fns (https://date-fns.org/)
4. Day.js (https://day.js.org/)

Example for moment.js :

- moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
- moment(Your date).format('MM/DD/YYYY');

Answer (score 0):

Trying to parse a string using the `Date` constructor shouldn't be done. This can give you unpredictable results in different browser platforms.

The best is to use a popular date library like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

It is as easy as this.

```
moment(str, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Here is the phrasing guide:
https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/